# Intrusive frame around Gedit windows in VirtualBox seamless mode

Tags: virtualbox, xubuntu, gedit

I run Xubuntu 16.04 in VirtualBox on Windows and I mostly view it in seamless mode. It works well for most apps but when there is a Gedit window overlapping the desktop or windows running in Windows, a frame around Gedit is shown, probably because of the shadow.

The shadow of Xubuntu windows is correctly shown where one Xubuntu window overlaps another and ignored when overlapping Windows. However, this does not work for Gedit.

[image: screenshot]

I went through Preferences in Gedit and have not found any option to change this. Is there any way to get rid of the distracting frame around Gedit windows?

Comment: Actually, I overcame this by switching from Gedit to gVim (`apt install vim-gtk`).

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of window borders by appending

```
decoration, decoration:backdrop {
    border-radius: 0;
    border-width: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    margin: 1px;
}
```

to `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` file (create it if it doesn't exist)

Note that while you can set the margin to 0 and get rid of the border completely, that would break ability to resize windows by dragging their edges.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried this but nothing seems to be changed…

Comment: @Melebius I only tested this on Xubuntu 20.04 and Virtualbox 6.1.8/6.0.20, could be that earlier versions need different selectors in that CSS file. (I did have to restart the program with the border in order for the changes to take effect)